# not able to set the timeout for cookie in the module installed

Tags: php, javascript

When I am opening my website for the 1st time, A popup related to cookie policy appears. After that I close that popup, after that it is never appearing,even if I am logging through the front end to the site even though its getting successfully logged in.

But if suppose if I am opening the site and closing the popup and after some time duration if I am logging to the site through the front end then again it is going to the front end without logging and that popup is again appearing.
So my main question or doubt is that ****How can I increase this timeout for this cookie***.* I am also not able to see any settings also in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date the cookie expires when you create it by setting expires in the value string. See: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

In php you can set the sessions time to live, see this post: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: Hi Johan, As I told that this popup is coming through a module so and code has already been written for this and here is one javascript page in which timeout has been defined but I am not able to see to set timeout in that code....here no attachment facility is available so that can send that javascript page.

Comment: Not knowing your code or module the only thing I can think of is that: If the cookie belongs to your website you should be able to access it and modify it's value by reading it, erasing it and creating it again.